# Solve for $z$ : $(z+1/z)^n=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have solved that $z+1/z= \cos (2k\pi/n)  + i \sin (2k\pi/n)$ where $k$ is integer,
then how can I continue?

Comment: You can now have a quadratic equation in $z$. Do you know how to solve general quadratics?

Comment: @Rócherz:  $z + 1/z = 2 \Re z$ iff $\vert z \vert = 1$, which isn't necessarily the case here.

Comment: @Rocherz:  the "if" direction is easy, since $\vert z \vert = 1 \Longrightarrow z = e^{i\theta}$; for "only if" write $z = a + bi$; then $1/z = (a - bi)/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ whence $z + 1/z = a + bi +  (a - bi)/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 2a$ or $ bi +  (a - bi)/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = a$; if either $a \ne 0$, $b \ne 0$ this implies $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 1 \Longrightarrow \vert z \vert = 1$. $OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may continue as follows:

setting

$\omega = e^{2 \pi i /n}, \tag 1$

we see that

$\omega^k = e^{2k \pi i / n} = \cos \dfrac{2k\pi}{n} + i \sin \dfrac{2k\pi}{n}, \; 0 \le k \le n - 1, \tag 2$

so with

$z + \dfrac{1}{z} = \omega^k, \tag 3$

we write

$z^2 - \omega^k z + 1 = 0, \tag 4$

and apply the quadratic formula:

$z = \dfrac{\omega^k \pm \sqrt{\omega^{2k} - 4}}{2}, \; 0 \le k \le n -1. \tag 5$